# Swift Grouping by Key in nested dictionary

Tags: swift, dictionary, filter

I have following json, which I'm trying to group using swift function.

```
{
  "response": [
    {
      "user": "A",
      "details": {
        "source": "Tab"
      }
    },
    {
      "user": "B",
      "details": {
        "source": "Tab"
      }
    },
    {
      "user": "C",
      "details": {
        "source": "Desktop"
      }
    },
    {
      "user": "D",
      "details": {
        "source": "Mobile"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

So what I tried is, grouping through "details" key, but it won't let me add source key in Grouping method.

> let groupedDict = Dictionary(grouping: items, by: { $0["device"] as!
>   [String: String] } )

The only way I can go with is to iterate each and every time and filter manually.

The output that I'm trying to achieve is as below:

```
{
  "Mobile": [
    {
      "user": "C",
      "details": {
        "source": "Mobile"
      }
    }
  ],
  "tab": [
    {
      "user": "A",
      "details": {
        "source": "Tab"
      }
    },
    {
      "user": "B",
      "details": {
        "source": "Tab"
      }
    }
  ],
  "Desktop": [
    {
      "user": "C",
      "details": {
        "source": "Desktop"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Any leads appreciated. TIA

**Edit:**

To be able to get it filtered in specific order. ie Mobile, Tab and Desktop as shown in response.

Comment: "To be able to get it filtered in specific order." Why that particular order while a Dictionary isn't sorted? `let dict = ["tab":"a", "Destkop": "b"]` should be the same as  `let dict = ["Destkop": "b", "tab":"a"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Follow three Steps**

1. Find Unique values of "source" key
2. GroupBy unique key and make Dictionary
3. Convert dictionary into Json

**Here is Code**

```
let response = jsonResult["response"] as! [[String :Any]]
```

Find Unique values of "source" key

```
let array = (response).map { ($0["details"] as! [String:Any])["source"] as! String }
let uniqueSourceKeyArray = Set.init(array)
```

GroupBy unique key and make Dictionary

```
var dictTemp = [String:Any]()
for obj in uniqueSourceKeyArray {
let dict = (response).filter({($0["details"] as! [String:Any])["source"] as! String == obj })
  dictTemp[obj] = dict
}
```

Convert dictionary into Json

```
if let jsonResult1 = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dictTemp, options: []) as?  Data {
  let finalJson = String.init(data: jsonResult1, encoding: .utf8)
  print(finalJson!)
}
```

**Result**

```
{"Tab":[{"user":"A","details":{"source":"Tab"}},{"user":"B","details":{"source":"Tab"}}],"Mobile":[{"user":"D","details":{"source":"Mobile"}}],"Desktop":[{"user":"C","details":{"source":"Desktop"}}]}
```

Comment: Your solution works well, but how about creating an array in specified order as Mobile, Tab and Desktop respectively ?

Comment: JSONSerialization can not convert into order json.. @Dhruv you need to convert it manual coding...

Answer (score 4):

I have achieved this, by

1 - `Decode` the response into an `Object`.

2 - filtered a 3 `arrays` of each type.

3 -  grouped those arrays.

Observe the code below.

```
struct MyObject: Codable {
    var response: [DataBody]
    struct DataBody: Codable {
        var user: String
        var details: Details
    }
    struct Details: Codable {
        var source: String
    }
}

let myObject = try? JSONDecoder().decode(MyObject.self, from: jsonData!)
let tabs = myObject!.response.filter({$0.details.source == "Tab"})
let desktops = myObject!.response.filter({$0.details.source == "Desktop"})
let mobiles =  myObject!.response.filter({$0.details.source == "Mobile"})

var grouped = Dictionary(grouping: myObject!.response, by: { $0.details.source })
[
    "Tab": tabs,
    "Desktop": desktops ,
    "Mobile": mobiles
]
```

> This is done using Swift4

We are not done yet,  to 100% check on the result

1- `encode`  grouped.

2- convert it to `String`

3- print.

Check it out.

```
let encdoedData = try!  JSONEncoder().encode(grouped)

let finalResult = String(data: encdoedData, encoding: .utf8)

print(finalResult!)
```

**Result:**

> {"Tab":[{"details":{"source":"Tab"},"user":"A"},{"details":{"source":"Tab"},"user":"B"}],"Desktop":[{"details":{"source":"Desktop"},"user":"C"}],"Mobile":[{"details":{"source":"Mobile"},"user":"D"}]}

Comment: I'm yet to try, but will it provide the output in above specified order ? Mobile, Tab and Desktop respectively.

Comment: look at grouped just change the order of the keys , mobile , tab , desktop